# What motivates the use of the co-area formula? What is co-area?

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

The motivation for the area formula is very clear. Given a set A in $\mathbf{R^n}$, and a Lipschitz function f $: \mathbf{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbf{R^{N}}$, what is the measure of the set f(A) in $R^{N}$. The area formula gives you the area f(A) in terms of the Jacobian associated with f.

But what is the co-area formula? WHat is coarea even? And what can we even do with the coarea formuöa?

Comment: Here's an informal explanation of what the coarea formula is but no explanation of why it's useful. https://deaneyang.github.io/blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/integration/2021/07/09/CoareaFormula.html